# fitting a GLMER model with glmmTMB

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a generalized linear mixed model with `glmmTMB`

```
summary(glmmTMB(cbind(SARA_ph58, 1)~ `Melk T`+VetT+EiwT+
    `VET EIWIT ratio`+LactT+CelT+UrmT+vetg+eiwitg+lactg+
    `DS opname`+`boluses per day`+`chewings per bolus`+
    `rumination (min/d)`+ Activiteit + (1|experiment),
     data = dataset1geenNA, family = binomial()))
```

When i run this code i get some output but is also get the next warning message:

> 1:  In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
> Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
> 2: In sqrt(diag(vcov)) : NaNs produced

does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Output:

```
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula:          cbind(SARA_ph58, 1) ~ `Melk T` + VetT + EiwT + `VET EIWIT ratio` +      LactT + CelT + UrmT + vetg + eiwitg + lactg + `DS opname` +  
    `boluses per day` + `chewings per bolus` + `rumination (min/d)` +      Activiteit + (1 | experiment)
Data: dataset1geenNA

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
      NA       NA       NA       NA       79 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups     Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 experiment (Intercept) 5.138e-08 0.0002267
Number of obs: 96, groups:  experiment, 3

Conditional model:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)          -1.595e+01  1.605e+01  -0.994   0.3202  
`Melk T`             -2.560e-01  1.330e-01  -1.925   0.0542 .
VetT                 -7.499e+00  3.166e+00  -2.369   0.0178 *
EiwT                  8.353e+00  4.885e+00   1.710   0.0872 .
`VET EIWIT ratio`     2.100e+01  1.545e+01   1.359   0.1742  
LactT                -2.086e+00  8.571e-01  -2.434   0.0149 *
CelT                 -1.430e-04  6.939e-04  -0.206   0.8367  
UrmT                  1.300e-02  3.978e-02   0.327   0.7438  
vetg                  1.166e-03         NA      NA       NA  
eiwitg               -2.596e-03  5.180e-03  -0.501   0.6162  
lactg                 7.862e-03         NA      NA       NA  
`DS opname`          -1.882e-02  8.416e-02  -0.224   0.8231  
`boluses per day`    -3.200e-02  1.226e-01  -0.261   0.7940  
`chewings per bolus`  1.758e-02  6.688e-02   0.263   0.7927  
`rumination (min/d)` -1.468e-03  3.145e-03  -0.467   0.6408  
Activiteit            4.265e-03  4.625e-03   0.922   0.3564
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: We need a lot more information to help you solve this.  The development version of `glmmTMB` has a `diagnose` function that might help you: see http://glmmtmb.github.io/glmmTMB/ for instructions about how to diagnose.  There is a basic troubleshooting vignette (the one pointed to in the warning message) [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html).  Can you at least show us the output?

Comment: @BenBolker i added a picture of the whole output, let me know if it readable for you.

Comment: Thanks, but if you can include the output as **text** (i.e. cut-and-paste from your R session) rather than as a screenshot that would be much better.  Put it in a code block; if you don't know how to do that, just put the text in and I or someone else will edit.

Comment: @BenBolker like this you mean?

Comment: yes ............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

The proximal problem is that you have a (near) **singular fit**: `glmmTMB` is trying to make the variance zero (5.138e-08 is as close as it can get). Because it fits on a log-variance (actually log-standard-deviation) scale, this means that it's trying to go to -∞, which makes the covariance matrix of the parameters impossible to estimate.

The main reason this is happening is that you have a very small number of groups (3) in your random effect (`experiment`).

These are extremely common issues with mixed models: you can start by reading `?lme4::isSingular` and the [relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1).

The simplest solution would be to treat `experiment` as a fixed effect, in which case you would no longer have a mixed model and you could back to plain `glm()`.

Another slightly worrying aspect of your code is the response variable `cbind(SARA_ph58, 1)`. If `SARA_ph58` is a *binary* (0/1) variable you can use just `SARA_ph58`. If you pass a two-column matrix as you are doing, the first column is interpreted as the number of successes and the second column as the number of failures; it looks like you may have been trying to specify that the **total number of trials** for each observation is 1 (again, if this is the case you can just use `SARA_ph58` as the response).

One final note is that `lme4::glmer` is a little more tolerant of singular fits than `glmmTMB`.

Comment: Thanks for you response, it is already a bit more clear and i'm going to study the relevant information. On the other hand, what is according to your knowledge,  the fastes way right now to the select the propper variables to include into my final GLMER model? I'm not restricted to only use the glmmTMB, could other(more easy commands, i'm just a beginner in R) commands also fix the job?

Thanks in advance again!!

Comment: Sorry, but that's a pretty big can of worms to tackle. I've made some more suggestions.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.